# Data Visualization and Interpretation in Segmented Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, data-visualization, segmented-regression

In the course of my research, I am examining the interplay between age, morningness-eveningness, and sex-specific trajectories. Initially, for a holistic overview, I generated a scatterplot featuring distinct lines for each gender. The x-axis delineates age, while the y-axis portrays morningness-eveningness scores based on a designated scale.

Subsequently, I conducted segmented regression analyses to delve deeper into sex-specific trajectories and pinpoint breakpoints in the relationship. It came to my attention that in the resulting graphs, the y-axis is labeled as the "effect of age," while the x-axis remains age. The term "effect of age" signifies the estimated change in the response variable associated with a one-unit change in age, correct? How can I best interpret this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If the issue is that the axis label changed at some point, that is going to be an issue with understanding how the code / packages you used work.  This doesn't sound like a question about statistics itself.